# batch crop quad images with diffenrent sizes to a circle

Tags: image, opencv, command-line, imagemagick, crop

I have lots of images of planets in differing sizes like

[image] [image] [image]
[image]

They are all positioned exactly in the middle of the square images but with different height.
Now I want to crop them and make the black border transparent. I tried with `convert` (ImageMagick 6.9.10-23) like this:

```
for i in planet_*.jpg; do
  nr=$(echo ${i/planet_/}|sed s/.jpg//g|xargs)
  convert $i -fuzz 1% -transparent black trans/planet_${nr}.png
done
```

But this leaves some artifacts like:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there a command to crop all images in a circle, so the planet is untouched? (It mustn't be imagemagick).

I could also imagine a solution where I would use a larger `-fuzz` value and then fill all transparent pixels in the inner planet circle with black.

Those are all planets, I want to convert: [download zip](https://framadrop.org/lufi/r/xZyupNVL_p#pf9g8cvzJU4wgFVgJAb9sGdN9V+l+IZZCdEcA/j90hc=)

Comment: It would be worth mentioning which version of Imagemagick you are using as the answer may be different.

Comment: Please actually identify the version.

Comment: ImageMagick does not have a Hough circle transform nor a fit to circle. You would be best to use OpenCV for these tasks. The only way I can see to do that in ImageMagick would be to iterate with drawing a circle, mask it out and test the brightness. Iterate to maximize the brightness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using Python Opencv from the minEclosingCircle.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# read image
img = cv2.imread('planet.jpg')
h, w, c = img.shape

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# get enclosing circle
center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(big_contour)
cx = int(round(center[0]))
cy = int(round(center[1]))
rr = int(round(radius))

# draw outline circle over input
circle = img.copy()
cv2.circle(circle, (cx,cy), rr, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# draw white filled circle on black background as mask
mask = np.full((h,w), 0, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.circle(mask, (cx,cy), rr, 255, -1)

# antialias
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0,0), sigmaX=2, sigmaY=2, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(blur, in_range=(127,255), out_range=(0,255))


# put mask into alpha channel to make outside transparent
imgT = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
imgT[:,:,3] = mask

# crop the image
ulx = int(cx-rr+0.5)
uly = int(cy-rr+0.5)
brx = int(cx+rr+0.5)
bry = int(cy+rr+0.5)
print(ulx,brx,uly,bry)
crop = imgT[uly:bry+1, ulx:brx+1]

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("planet_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("planet_circle.jpg", circle)
cv2.imwrite("planet_mask.jpg", mask)
cv2.imwrite("planet_transparent.png", imgT)
cv2.imwrite("planet_crop.png", crop)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("circle", circle)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Circle on input:

[image]

Mask image:

[image]

Transparent image:

[image]

Cropped transparent image:

[image]

### packages to install

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv python3-sklearn python3-skimage
```

Comment: that looks perfect, I saved it as `planet2png.py` and installed `apt install python3-opencv python3-sklearn`, which works perfect ;) I added file input and output handling here: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/164e671f82f335943ab936e0ba715907

Comment: I only get one error with this planet: https://spacetrace.org/pics/system/planet_s1_299.jpg - `crop planet_s1_299.jpg
20 74 -2 51
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "planet2png.py", line 96, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "planet2png.py", line 83, in main
    cv2.imwrite("thresh/"+outputfile, thresh)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) ../modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:661: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'imwrite_'
`

Comment: Is there a way to smooth or antialias the borders?

Comment: The error is in your environment and not having a way to write the output format. What format is that file?

Comment: I have added code to antialias the mask (basically a blur and clip and stretch the dynamic range). I note that I had left in an unused Skimage module from a previous post. However the antialiasing does require the skimage.exposure module to be imported.

Comment: I added the needed packages to your answer and fix cropping of the bottom and right side. The antialias is great (I only changed `sigmaX=1, sigmaY=1`). My environment is ok, I can write all files. there is only one problem with that image. your script doesn't get the thresh right there and has a negative value. There are some few other images, where the circle doesn't correctly hit the planet and is way off to the side (I added the 4th image to my question).

Comment: Isn't there a way to cut out always the same center circle? All my planets have the same ratio and they are always in the middle, so `findContours` is a nice feature, but here it is not really perfect. better would be to just use a circle that is 10% off from the corners

Comment: Those are all planets, I want to convert: https://framadrop.org/lufi/r/xZyupNVL_p#pf9g8cvzJU4wgFVgJAb9sGdN9V+l+IZZCdEcA/j90hc=

Comment: Get the circle arguments from one image. Make the binary mask. Then scale the mask to the same size as each input image. Then antialias it with appropriately modified blur arguments for the image size. Larger images may need more blur sigma than smaller ones, but not by too much. You may get by with the same blur. Then put the mask into the alpha channel of the image. Then crop according to scaled crop values.

Comment: Is there another way than blur? Because, if I cut out the outside of a circle in Gimp, I get a much nicer sharp edge. I think, that is anti-alias, not blur

Comment: I know of no other way. You can adjust the blur and also the values in the skimage method. Keep the output at 0 and 255. But you can try changing either or both of the input values. Try 0.4*255 and 0.6*255. Or just increase the low value of the input